# PHP set value for class

Tags: php, function, class, object

I have two PHP classes (DBOperations.php and functions.php). Now I want to set a value in the DBOperations.php class from the functions.php class.

```
class DBOperations{

    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'u';
    public $database;
    private $pass = 'p';
    private $conn;

public function __construct() {



    $this -> conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".$this -> host.";dbname=".$this -> database, $this -> user, $this -> pass);

    }
 public function doMagic() {
 //running mysql queries here
 }
```

and functions.php:

```
require_once 'DBOperations.php';

class Functions{

private $db;

public function __construct() {

       $this -> db = new DBOperations(); 
}
public function doThings($variable) {

  $db = $this -> db;
  //here I want to set the value $database from the DBOperations class to //$variable
```

Can someone help nme out?

Regards Francis

Comment: `$this -> db -> database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it in functions.php class function by setting in function property like

```
public function doThings($variable) {

  $db = $this -> db;
   $this->db->database = 'dbname';
   // same for all variables if they are public
}
```